# How to navigate between 2 views on navigation drawer menu click in React Native Android?

Tags: javascript, android, navigation-drawer, react-native

I am unable to understand the navigator flow for react-native-android.
I am referring following link:
https://rnplay.org/apps/HPy6UA

But this is related to IOS. Can I able to use same code for react-native Android also ?

I am also referring this:
https://github.com/caroaguilar/NavigationDrawerExample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Navigator` component works on Android the same way it does on iOS. The main idea is that you have an array of routes. In order to go back to a previous route, you just need to remove the last route from the array (it is `this.props.navigator.pop();` in your example). If you need to go to a next route, you need to push it to the array.

Please let me know if you have any specific questions.

Comment: I have used `Navigator` to navigate between screens. But I am unable to set `title` to next screen. 
`<Navigator initialRoute={{ title: 'Awesome Scene', index: 0 }} renderScene={(route, navigator) => <Text>Hello {route.title}!</Text> } style={{padding: 100}} />` 
By using this, title is **blank** for now.

Comment: When you push a new route, you need to pass the title property: `navigator.push({title: 'Title 2'})`. 

You can also use the initialRouteStack attribute of the Navigator as it is demonstrated in the official example: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#additional-scenes